# Define method signature for passthrough method defined in super class in Ruby with Sorbet

Tags: ruby, types, sorbet

We're considering adopting [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org/) and I wanted to know if it's possible to define the signature of the following method. This is a common pattern we use: there is an abstract `Service` class that has a `call` class method which is responsible for both initializing the class and calling the `call` instance method on it.

```rb
# typed: true

class Service
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Helpers

  abstract!

  def self.call(...)
    new(...).call
  end

  sig{abstract.void}
  def call
  end
end

class ServiceA < Service
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Helpers

  sig{params(a: String).void}
  def initialize(a:)
    @a = a
  end

  sig{override.void}
  def call
    puts @a
  end
end

ServiceA.call(a: 'some value')
```

Basically the params for `self.call` must match the params of the subclass's initializer and its return value must match the subclass's return value for the `call` instance method. Is there a way to do this with Sorbet?

Here is the error I get.

```
editor.rb:10: Splats are only supported where the size of the array is known statically https://srb.help/7019
```

Comment: As the sorbet doc already states, splats are not very well supported by Sorbet.
However, you can still type-check the base service if you're happy with the constraint that your services will only accept positional arguments. You can do so following this example: https://cutt.ly/40Pgahg. Since your question is being reviewed, I can't post this as an answer yet, I'll do so later once it's approved with the full code snippet

Comment: Sorry I actually meant "your services will only accept keyword arguments"*

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer. So I think the two shortcomings of Sorbet here would be (1) kwargs only which is not a huge deal and also (2) return value of the call method can't be overridden.

Comment: When you override, the return value must be a subclass of what the original implementation states. So if your abstract class returns T.untyped, you can override that with any other type on the subclasses.

I've also added my previous comment as an answer now, I would appreciate if you could accept that if it helped :)

Comment: The instance `call` method is not used directly. The class `call` method is used when calling services and it's return value must match that of the instance method. I tried defining it as `T.untyped` but it's not being overriden in the subclass since I'm only defining the instance method in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

As the sorbet doc already states, splats are not very well supported by Sorbet. However, you can still type-check the base service if you're happy with the constraint that your services will only accept positional arguments. You can do so following this example:

```
# typed: true

class Service
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Helpers

  abstract!

  def self.call(**kwargs)
    new(**kwargs).call
  end
  
  def initialize(**kwargs); end

  sig { abstract.void }
  def call; end
end

class ServiceA < Service
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Helpers

  sig { override.params(a: String).void }
  def initialize(a:)
    @a = a
  end

  sig{ override.void }
  def call
    puts @a
  end
end

ServiceA.call(a: 'some value')
```